# How to get Returned value from a Keyword called under Run Keyword If in Robot Framework?

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

I have written a keyword for Testcase teardown in my Robot Testsuite. Which is mentioned below:

```
*** Keyword ***
Result Evaluation
@{TRACEFILE} =  evalVirdict  ${value[2]}
:FOR  ${ELEMENT}  IN  @{TRACEFILE}
\    Log  ${ELEMENT}
\    Run Keyword if  '${TEST STATUS}'=='FAIL'  readerrlines  ${ELEMENT}
```

In the above Keyword `evalVirdict` is a function written in python and `${value[2]}` is coming from my Testcases and in `Run Keyword if  '${TEST STATUS}' == 'FAIL'  readerrlines  ${ELEMENT}` part. I am calling another function `readerrlines` which returns some value. The `readerrlines` function definition is below:

```
def readerrlines(tracefile):
    errVal = []
    for line in list(open(tracefile)):
        line = line.strip()
        mat = re.match(r'.*\s.*\s+:\s\*+(.*\s)\s{1}', line)
        if mat:
            err = mat.group(1).strip()
            errVal.append(err)
    return errVal
```

Here i want to know how to get this returned value from readerrlines functions in `Run Keyword if  '${TEST STATUS}' == 'FAIL'  readerrlines  ${ELEMENT}` ?

I have tried `Run Keyword if  '${TEST STATUS}' == 'FAIL' @{errval} =  readerrlines  ${ELEMENT}` but got an error as Non-Existing variable @{errval} and   also `Run Keyword if  '${TEST STATUS}' == 'FAIL'  Set Variable  @{errval} =  readerrlines  ${ELEMENT}` with no error and no output as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Run Keyword If` will return the result of the keyword it is running. Thus, you would do:

```
${result}=    Run Keyword If    '${TEST STATUS}'=='FAIL'  readerrlines  ${ELEMENT}
```